# How to read from a specific line of a file

Tags: java, android

I have a text file (called `data.txt`, which has 350 lines)

How can I find the text on a given line of the file? For example:

```
int imageVariable = 5;
String imageText = nthLineOfFile(imageVariable);
textView1.setText(imageText);
```

I'm trying to write the `String nthLineOfFile(int image)` function.

Thanks

Comment: Is `data.txt` something you generate at runtime or an asset you include with your app? (Side question I know, but sometimes the solution is better data management)

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
String str = FileUtils.readLines(file).get(lineNumber);
```

or you may use the conventional way by using `BufferedReader` class:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
for (int i = 0; i < lineNumber - 1; i++)
{
   r.readLine();
}
return r.readLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Scanner`:

```
Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(your file);
for (int i = 0; i < lineNum - 1; i++) {
    fileIn.nextLine(); // ignore
}
nthLine = fileIn.nextLine();
```